# Is There a way to sort by .column of a drop down field in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to sort a form by two fields: [datakey] and [employeenumber].column(1) and I cannot get it to work.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.OrderBy = "datakey, employeenumber"
    Me.OrderByOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your response but the emplyeenumber is a dropdown box with both the number and in column(1) the name associated with it.  I am trying to sort by the name, [employeenumber].column(1),

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can only sort by columns that are member of the form's recordsource.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to join the field you use in `Column(1)` in the record source of the form itself. Then you can sort by this field.